# npm: Where do the children dependencies come from?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

[I read on github that](https://github.com/pghalliday/grunt-mocha-test):

> grunt-mocha-test uses npm's Peer Dependencies functionality

I was unsure what "Peer Dependencies" were so I checked the npm docs and found:

> npm is awesome as a package manager. In particular, it handles
>   sub-dependencies very well: if my package depends on request version 2
>   and some-other-library

Which I take to mean:

1. Having 'peer dependencies' mean that a dependency could need other
   dependencies in order to function correctly.
2. npm creates a tree like structure, where the dependency is the root,
   and the root dependency has children dependencies

The questions I am left with are:

**Where do the children dependencies come from? Are they copies? Or are they
references to other dependencies already present in package.json?**

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are asking, but if in your package.json you have as dependencies A, B and C and each of them depends on X, each of them will have a copy of X in node_modules/AorBorC/node_modules/X

Comment: So in that example, would each thing have its OWN copy of x? Or would each have a reference to the same x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of them will have a copy of the package. For example, if you have a project with those dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "node-handlebars": "*",
    "less-file": "*",
    "async-ls": "*",
    "promise": "4.0.0"
}
```

and run `npm install`, you would have 4 copies of `promise` (the one you declared as a dependency and 3 others needed from each of the other dependencies)

```
$ find . -name promise
./node_modules/async-ls/node_modules/promise
./node_modules/promise
./node_modules/node-handlebars/node_modules/promise
./node_modules/less-file/node_modules/promise
```

Note that this would happen even if every one depends on a specific version of `promises` package (ex `4.0.0`).

Despite looking a little redundant I guess this makes dependency management a lot easier, and nowadays the extra space used in general should be negligible.